# Terraform cidrsubnets loop for 100 subnets

Tags: terraform, subnet, infrastructure-as-code

I currently testing out terraform for deployment and i need a quite large list of subnets generated

I found that i can generate the list i need by using the following block

```
cidrsubnets("10.10.0.0/18", 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
```

And adding additional newbits for each i need. However when a large list is needed, this quickly gets out of hand and was wondering how i can specify a number of needed subnets or an end address or something similar to specify the amount i need, rather than having 100 newbits for an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can auto generate multiple subnets using [argument expansion](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/function-calls.html#expanding-function-arguments) and [for expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html):

```
cidrsubnets("10.10.0.0/18", [for v in range(100): 9]...)
```